# Kleene post theorem

Tags: logic, computability

Recall Kleene-Post's theorem says that there exists A and B $\leq_T \emptyset'$ that are incomparable.

Recall $\cup_s \sigma_s= A$ and $\cup_s \tau_s= B$ where $\sigma_s$ and $\tau_s$ are decided with oracle $\emptyset'$.

Why is it that given an oracle $\emptyset'$, A and B become decidable? I think the reason is that given x $\in \omega$ we may decide its existence in A by computing $\sigma_x$ with each $\sigma_{y \leq x}$ taking finite construction time.

Comment: Yes. Using $\emptyset'$ you can first define $\sigma_0$, then $\tau_0$, then $\sigma_1$, ..., all the way up to a $\sigma_n$ of length greater than $x$ (usually $n=x$, as you say). This takes only finitely many steps, and $x$ is in $A$ iff $x$ is in $\sigma_n$.

Answer (score 1):

$A\le_T \emptyset^\prime$ means we can find a $\emptyset^\prime$-recursive function of a characteristic function of $A$. That is, under the oracle $\emptyset^\prime$, we have a effective procedure that computes the characteristic function of $A$.